# Dynamics: band or music

Tags: terminology, vocabulary

Is it safe to say, "The inclusion of the saxophone has changed the dynamics of the **band**" or is this one correct "The inclusion of the saxophone has changed the dynamics of the **music**"?

Comment: Whichever is most appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"dynamics of the music" would suggest to me the actual volume of sound produced, or at least how much it varied, had changed (and given an instrument has been added, this might be just a fancy way of saying 'the music was louder').
"Dynamics of the band" doesn't really convey that, and in fact could even be referring to the interpersonal relationships within the band, quite apart from what music they made.

Answer (score 2):

Both are grammatically correct and both are meaningful.

> "The inclusion of the saxophone has changed the dynamics of the band"

This means that the band members interact differently now that a saxophone (player) has joined.

> "The inclusion of the saxophone has changed the dynamics of the music"

This means that the music sounds different now that a saxophone (player) has joined the ensemble.

Which do you want it to mean?

Comment: Oh...So they are both correct. I want to talk about the sound changing when the sax was included so the second one would be the obvious answer, right? I was quite hesitant at first but thanks for clearing it up.

Comment: ***dynamic*** (no 's') could also be appropriate with respect to the band. *An interactive system or process, especially one involving competing or conflicting forces* The addition of the saxophone could dramatically alter how the instruments work together to produce the band's sound.